# SUMIF with more than three criteria

Tags: excel, google-sheets, spreadsheet

i'm trying to use a SUMIF with multiple criteria but it isn't working in google spreadsheets.

right now i have

```
=SUMIF($B$8:$B,"1",$C$8:$C,H8:H,"Direct")
```

i want "Direct" to be the sub criteria, so it only sums rows with that all in it.

Comment: @pnuts because it's often a similar syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SUMIF with multiple criteria doesn't exist, you should be using SUMIFS.  Your setup would be as follows:

`SUMIFS(sum_range1, criteria_range1, criterion1, criteria_range2, criterion2)`

Formula edited to reflect comments below.

Comment: thanks. what if the sum range is the same but i want two criteria?

Comment: There's no "sum-range2" in SUMIFS, only one sum range is allowed so the correct syntax is like this: `=SUMIFS(sum_range, criteria_range1, criterion1, criteria_range2, criterion2)` which is what you want for one sum range with 2 criteria - you can keep adding criteria ranges and criteria. The syntax is the same in Excel and google

Comment: @rs202 As barry mentioned you shouldn't need to worry about that.